# Using serializable in hibernate what underlying database types do i use

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, serializable

I need to use a serializable type in hibernate (to store a Subject (security)) All this works fine.

I just need to know what the underlying database types are for the following databases:

- MSSQL - I used 'image'
- db2 -
- postgre -
- mysql -

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say:

- MSSQL - I used 'image'
- db2 - BLOB(2G)
- postgre - [bytea](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/datatype-binary.html)
- mysql - One of the [BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) types

Comment: Thanks.. is the BLOB on db2, just BLOB? or a specific 2g?? type?